# Vshsost.exe has stopped working

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am debug a code in server 2008 but it showing an error like vshost.exe has stopped working. I am unable to debug the code. Please try 2 solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable the "Visual Studio hosting process":
"Project" -> "[ProjectName] Properties..". -> "Debug" -> Disable "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process".
The same solution for crash problem when debug WinForm application and Console application.